# why aren't the platform specific integer types in C and C++ (short, int, long) deprecated?

Tags: c++, c, data-types

TL;DR: Why isn't everybody screaming, "Don't use `short`, `int`, and `long` unless you really need to, and you very likely don't need to!"

---

I understand that, in theory, by using the types `short`, `int`, and `long`, you let the compiler choose the length that is most efficient for the given processor.

But is this a case of premature optimization being the root of all evil?

Suppose I have an integer variable that I know will always hold numbers from 1 to 1000. My understanding is that, assuming I am not worried about the memory difference between two and four bytes, the proponents of `short`/`int`/`long` would have me make that variable an `int` because that way the compiler can choose 16 bits or 32 bits depending on what is more efficient for the processor. If I had made it a `uint16_t`, the compiler may not be able to make code that is quite as fast.

But on modern hardware is that even true? Or rather, is the speed that's going to gain me (if any), really worth the much more likely possibility that using an imprecise type leads to a major bug in my program? For instance, I might use `int` throughout my program and think of it as representing a 32 bit value because that's what it's represented on every platform I've used for the past 20 years, but then my code is compiled on an unusual platform where `int` is two bytes and all sorts of bugs happen.

And aside from bugs, it just seems like an annoyingly imprecise way for programmers to talk about data. As an example, here is the definition that [Microsoft gives](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/ns-guiddef-guid) in 2019 for a GUID structure:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  unsigned long  Data1;
  unsigned short Data2;
  unsigned short Data3;
  unsigned char  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

Because of what a Uuid is, that long *has* to mean 32 bits, those shorts *have* to mean 16 bits, and that char *has* to mean 8 bits. So why continue to talk in this imprecise language of "short", "long" and (heaven help us) "long long"?

Comment: I agree that the naming convention and justification has become absurd. The default behaviour (and most convenient syntax) should surely be to specify a fixed size determined by the programmer.

Comment: Paradoxically, sometimes you can express your intent more precisely by being imprecise. Being too precise carries with it a lot of mental baggage. In many cases, if a code specifically asks that a number be uint16, that comes with the semantic implication that upcasting this number to uint32 is probably semantically incorrect (e.g. in a code that parse fixed-sized packets), but compilers will happily promote the number automatically. OTOH, by using imprecise types, you precisely communicated to other programmers that the precise type size of the number is irrelevant (e.g. just a loop counter).

Comment: @LieRyan, in my view that is not a case of expressing your intent *more clearly* with imprecision, but expressing no specific intent and letting the compiler fill in the gaps and make the assumptions.

Comment: Having suffered through dealing with a 16 bit system that was sending binary messages to a system that changed from 16 to 32 bit, I would say that if the year is 1990, you are completely right.  However, in 2019, when most things either won't interact with 16 bit systems, or use formats without fixed data sizes (like JSON), you are no longer right.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. "Don't use `short`, `int`, and `long` unless you really need to, and you very likely don't need to!" That may be true, but as this also indicates, there are cases in which `short`, `int` and `long` _are_ needed. Since you only ever deprecate things that are not needed anymore, these types would obviously not be deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I understand that, in theory, by using the types short, int, and long, you let the compiler choose the length that is most efficient for the given processor.

That is only partially true. All those types have a [guaranteed minimum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815180/guarantateed-minimum-size-range-of-c-data-types) in ANSI C (AFAIK even in ANSI C89). Code relying only on those minimum sizes is still portable. Cases where the maximum size of a type matters to portability are way less frequent. Said that, I have seen (and written) lots of code over the years where `int` was assumed to be 32 bit as minimum, written clearly for environments with >=32 bit CPUs at minimum.

> But is this a case of premature optimization [...]?

Premature optimization is not only about optimizing for speed. It is about investing **extra effort** into code, and making code **more complicated**, for a (often pathological) "just in case" reason. "Just in case it could be slow" is only one of those potential reasons. So avoiding the usage of `int` "just in case" it could be ported to a 16 bit platform in the future could also be seen as a form of premature optimization, when this kind of porting will likely never happen.

Said that, I think the part you wrote about `int` is to some degree correct: in case there is any evidence a program might get ported from a 32 to a 16 bit platform, it would be best not to rely on `int` having 32 bits, and to use either `long`, a [specific C99 data type like `int32_t` or `int_least32_t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types) whereever one is unsure whether 16 bits are enough, or not. One could also use a global `typedef` to define `int32_t` on platforms which are not C99 compliant. All of this is a little bit of extra effort (at least in teaching the team which special data types were used in the project, and why).

See also [this older SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413521/is-there-any-reason-not-to-use-fixed-width-integer-types-e-g-uint8-t), for which the top most answer says, most people don't need that degree of portability.

And to your example about the GUID structure: the shown data structure seems to be mostly ok, it uses data types which are guaranteed to be large enough for each of the parts on each ANSI compliant platform. So even if someone tries to use this structure for writing portable code, that would perfectly be possible.

As you noted by yourself, if someone would try to use this structure as a spec for a GUID, they could complain about the fact it is to some degree imprecise and that it requires the read the documentation in full for getting an unambigous spec. This is one of the less frequent cases where maximum size of the types may matter.

Other problems could arise when the content of such a `struct` is string-formatted, binary serialized, stored or transmitted somewhere, whilst making assumptions about the individual maximum size of each field, or the total size being exactly 128 bit, the endianness, or the precise binary encoding of those data types. But since the documentation of the GUID struct does not make any promises about the underlying binary representation, one should not make any assumptions about it when trying to write portable code.

Comment: The fixed-width types aren't more portable, but more rigidly defined. Take care vis a vis relative width to `int` and its implications. Also, prepare for breakage on any platform not supplying that specific type you demand, which happens quite a lot for DSP and embedded.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I have made my answer more specific to the case "porting from 32 bit to 16 bit" to make it more clear.

Comment: The issue with the GUID doc from Microsoft is that they explicitly describe a GUID as having 128 bits, so obviously that struct would be problematic as you describe.  But I believe all Microsoft compilers use the same widths and that struct isn't meant to be portable to all platforms.

Answer (score 8):

They're not deprecated because there's no reason to deprecate them.

I'm almost tempted to leave it at that, because there's honestly not a lot more that really needs to be said--deprecating them would accomplish precisely nothing, so nobody's written a paper trying to deprecate them, and I can't quite imagine anybody bothering to write such a paper either (except, I suppose, perhaps as an April Fool's joke, or something on that order).

But, let's consider a typical use of `int`:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout << "something or other\n";
```

Now, would anybody gain anything by changing `i` to an `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t`, or something similar? I'd posit that the answer is a resounding "no". We'd gain essentially nothing at all.

Now, it's certainly true that there are situations where it makes sense to use explicitly sized types such as `int8_t`, `int16_t` and `int32_t` (or their unsigned variants).

But, part of the intent of C and C++ is to support system programming, and for that, there are definitely times I want a type that reflects the exact size of a register on the target machine. Given that this is an explicit intent of both C and C++, deprecating types that support that makes no sense at all.

What it really comes down to is pretty simple: yes, there are cases where you want a type that's a specific number of bits--and if you need that, C and C++ provide types that are guaranteed to be exactly the size you specify. But there are also cases where you don't care much about the size, as long as it's large enough for the range you're using--and C and C++ provide types to satisfy that need as well.

From there, it's up to you, the programmer, to know what you really want, and act appropriately. Yes, you've pointed to a case where somebody (at least arguably) made a poor choice. But that doesn't mean it's always a poor choice, or even necessarily a poor choice most of the time.

Another thing to keep in mind is that although there are cases where portability is important, there are also a lot where it matters little, and still others where it doesn't matter at all. At least in my experience, however, sizes of integer types are rarely a significant factor in portability. On one hand, it's probably true that if you looked at a lot of current code, there's undoubtedly quite a bit that actually depends on `int` being at least 32 bits, rather than the 16 bits specified by the standards. But, if you tried to port most of that code to (say) a compiler for MS-DOS that used 16-bit `int`s, you'd quickly run into much larger problems, such as the fact that they were using that `int` to index into an array of around 10 million `double`s--and your real problem in porting the code is a lot less with that `int` than with storing 80 million bytes on a system that only supports 640K.

Comment: "there are definitely times I want a type that reflects the exact size of a register on the target machine" – well, but none of the types asked about in this question do that, no? I'm not a C programmer, but I am pretty sure that there is nothing in the spec that says that any of those types is in any way related to the size of a register. In fact, different operating systems use different conventions *on the same CPU* (e.g. ILP64 vs. LP64 vs. ILP32), so they clearly *cannot* be related to the register size.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: `int` is supposed to: "have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment;", which (at least on a register based machine normally means the register size, but yes, it's based on the "execution environment", not necessarily the actual hardware, so a 32-bit compiler on 64-bit hardware will still normally have 32-bit int.

Comment: Many people want an 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit type. The “smallest” types are char, short and int. If int was 64 bit, we would lose one of 8, 26 and 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated today means gone tomorrow.

The cost of removing these types from C and C++ would be incredibly high. Not just causing unneeded work, but also likely to cause bugs all over the place.

Comment: Does it? There are parts of the JRE that have been deprecated for 20 years and are still there.

Comment: It took the standards committee decades to deprecate standard library functions like `gets()`.  They had clear, serious problems, but for a long time those were overshadowed by the problems that would be created by changing the spec.  I can't imagine they'd ever justify deprecating something that - while a bit quirky - isn't causing real problems that can't be handled by the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation for GUID should be read in conjunction with the [Microsoft's C++ compiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019) platform-specific definitions of those values, which has a well defined sizes for those types, not the ANSI C/C++ standards' definition. So in a sense, the sizes of those GUID fields are well defined in Microsoft's compilers.

The GUID header is of course buggy in non-Microsoft platforms, but the error here is in thinking that Microsoft gives a damn about standard and other implementations.

Comment: *"The GUID header is of course buggy in non-Microsoft platforms"* - why precisely? Can you point out something in the documentation which  won't be true on a different ANSI C/C++ platform?

Comment: @DocBrown: using Microsoft's GUID header for non-Microsoft platforms can mean that the struct can be initialised to and can store invalid GUIDs as the fields can store values outside the expected range for GUID. Any programmer (that are a stickler about correctness) that uses this header unmodified outside of Microsoft systems would have to add checks that the values are within correct range before doing any operations on it.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds more like unfounded Microsoft bashing than a valid reason not to use this kind of struct definition for GUIDs. If some piece of code makes some strange operation which tries to leave the allowed range of those data types, this code would be buggy on any system, not just on Windows. And using fixed-size integer types would not change this.

Comment: @Doc Brown: You need to read again, I didn't say they will be buggy in Microsoft system, but rather they will be buggy on non-Microsoft systems as the headers makes platform specific assumptions. If some piece of code does some operation that leaves the allowed range, they'll just overflow in Microsoft system because they have the assumed sizes but wouldn't violate its class invariant. In other systems, they may not overflow at the correct wrapping points. This is why fixed size structures should have been defined with explicit fixed size types, and not rely on platform specific conventions.

Comment: @DocBrown Take the simple operation of formatting the Data1 chunk of the GUID as hex for example. In systems where long stores up to 8 hex digits, your code will be fine with just straight conversion to hex and zero padding it to 8 characters. But in systems where long actually can store 16 hex digits, you additionally also have to mask the high bits, as otherwise the Data1 section of the GUID can be longer than 8 hex digits with the naive formatting operation.

Comment: This is true, but I think that the last paragraph is somewhat unfair.  This is a header that is shipped with Microsoft compilers, and is not open sourced.  It is not unreasonable for them to not bother making it work for non Microsoft compilers if they are not licensing it for that usage.  The boost [uuid](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/uuid/uuid.hpp), which is meant to be portable, also has very explicit sizes.  (And is also *much* more complicated)

Comment: Anyone whose ever written code to be portable to non-Windows compilers knows that you have to avoid all non-standard headers like this one.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. My one is: this kind of data structure is not a problem in itself, it is not "buggy", as you wrote literally. However, I agree, it introduces some extra possibilities for writing accidentally non-portable code when using it blindly. That is exactly what I wrote in my answer: caring for portability requires extra effort, so may be seen as a form of premature optimization if the portability may never be required.

Comment: @DocBrown and Gort, thanks for the discussion. But my issue with the "platform specific types" in the GUID was less about whether the Microsoft code was buggy or even non-portable, and more just that it is a vague/indirect way to talk about the elements of that structure. It may not be well-defined if you happen to know the fixed sizes of those MS types, but still it "hides" the meaningful sizes of those fields, requiring that knowledge, instead of making them more plain to see/understand.

Comment: @MKatz: you are right, I missed that aspect. I think I should edit my answer to take this into account. As I wrote in my answer, cases where the maximum sizes of data types really matter are less frequent than cases where they don't matter. Using the GUID structure for documentation purposes may be one of those less frequent cases.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled C code (typically) runs natively, and native word sizes vary (they were especially variable in the early ‘70s when C was first developed).  You still have code running on 16-bit machines, machines where word sizes aren’t powers of 2 (9-bit bytes, 36-bit words), machines that use padding bits, etc.

Each type guarantees that it can represent a *minimum range of values*.  `int` is guaranteed to represent values in *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`, meaning it’s *at least* 16 bits wide.  On modern desktop and server systems it tends to be 32 bits wide, but that’s not guaranteed.

So no, the bit widths of `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc, are not fixed, and this is a *good* thing from C’s perspective.  It’s what has allowed C to be ported to such a wide variety of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of like talking.

If you talk to yourself, it really does not matter what language, sounds, etc., you use, you will probably understand yourself.

If you talk to someone else, there are specific rules that ***must*** be followed in order for both parties to clearly understand. The *language* matters. The *grammar* rules for the *language* matter. *Meanings* of specific phrases or words matter. When *language* is written, the *spelling* matters, and the *layout* on the page matters.

You are free to not conform with the rules and standards, but other parties are not likely to understand, and you may even cause damage by insulting or using phrases that are ambiguous.  Wars have been fought due to failures in communication.

In software there are analogous rules and standards.

If the software does not need to exchange information with any other systems, then yes, use of short/long is unnecessary in most cases as long as the data you are processing fits into the containers you define or use -- overflow is still possible.

If -- on the other hand -- the software exchanges information with another system, then that software ***must*** be aware of how that information is structured.

For example:

***Networking*** -- packets absolutely *must* have correct byte-order -- little-endian vs big-endian -- and fields within the packet *must* be the correct number of bits.  Even when you think you are sending 'obvious' data like JSON, that data must be converted into network packets that may be much shorter than the total data in your JSON stream, and the packets also have fields for packet type, for sequencing -- so you can reassemble the data on the receiving end -- for error detection and correction, and much *much* ***much*** more. All of the possible network packets ***must*** be defined in such a way that there can be no ambiguity on either sender's or receiver's part.  For this to be possible you ***must*** be able to specify exact sizes for packet fields that work with existing systems and systems which will use those packets in the future.

***Device Control*** -- Very similar to *networking* when you think about it -- where the packet 'fields' roughly correspond to device registers, bits, memory, etc., and controlling a specific device roughly corresponds to using a specific NIC or to the network IP address.  You 'send' a 'packet' by writing bits to specific locations, and you 'receive' a 'packet' by reading bits from specific locations. If you are not the device creator -- as it typical -- you ***must*** follow the 'protocol' spelled out by the creator in the device *datasheet*. The *fields* (registers) have the be the correct size. The bits have to be in the correct location. The registers ***must*** be correctly located in the system's address or I/O space.  The device creator tells you the 'protocol' for exchanging data with the device.  The system designer tells you the 'protocol' -- address space and mapping -- for accessing the device.

You are free to do whatever you want in the software you write, but it is likely that the other party -- network recipient, specific device, etc. -- will not understand what you think you are doing, and in some cases you can even damage the system.

The [Ping-of-Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death) is a network example where intentional violation of the packet format resulted in crashing network receivers that presumed network packets would be correctly formed.

The [Fork-Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) is a system example where intentional abuse of system fork 'protocol' can hang a system until rebooted.

The [Buffer-Overrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) is a program example where assuming "everything just works" fails when someone (even yourself as the programmer) puts too much data into a container which cannot hold it.